# Django views in modules in "views" package, call by module name - Namespacing problem

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

My views.py is getting large, and I'd like to organize different parts of my django website by functionality. I envision something like this:

```
urls.py
views
├── __init__.py
├── editor.py
└── display.py
```

In my urls.py I'd like to have **seperated namespaces** like this:

```
url(r'^display_some_post/$', views.display.post, name="display_post"),
url(r'^edit_some_post/$', views.editor.post, name="editor_post"),
```

Note that every view is called by it's module name.

But I can't quite figure out the correct way to set up **init**.py and / or import the modules into the urls.py. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Are you using different apps in your project? That is the idiomatic way in Django to separate functionality out. Each app will have its own `views.py` (as well as `models.py`, `forms.py` etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you imported the **"views.py"** file like this before:

```
import .views
```

simply change it to:

```
import .views.display 
import .views.editor
```

In this case you can leave the **init**.py empty.
It's just there to indicate the folders files can be used as Python packages.

Take care.